# How to delete the empty cells in the rows when the data has been deleted using user form

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Hi currently i have a user form that allow me to delete the selected rows based on the user input of the project ID and it will delete the entire row of that project ID. However, when the data is deleted, the empty rows is not deleted and remain empty. Thus, i would have to manually delete the empty rows myself after the data in the row have been deleted using the delete command button. Is there any additional code i have to add in into my current code that i have so that once the data is deleted in that particular row, the empty row will also be deleted automatically?
Below is the code that i have for my delete command button.

```
Private Sub CommandDeleteButton1_Click()

    Dim lastrow
    Dim ProjCode As String
    Dim LabelProjName As String
    Dim LabelObjective As String
    Dim LabelProjSponsor As String
    Dim LabelProjSponsorNew As String
    Dim LabelProjManager As String
    Dim LabelRegulatory As String
    Dim LabelRiskLvl As String
    Dim LabelDatePar As Date
    Dim LabelCostPar As Long
    Dim LabelAffectCust As String
    Dim LabelCustNonRetail As String
    Dim LabelCustRetail As String
    Dim LabOutsourcingImp As String
    Dim LabelKeyUpdate As String
    Dim LabelSector As String

         lastrow = Sheets("Program Status Summary").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
         ProjCode = TextBoxProjCode.Text

            For currentrow = 4 To 100
                If Cells(currentrow, 2).Text = ProjCode Then
                    Cells(currentrow, 2).EntireRow.ClearContents
                End If

    Next currentrow

TextBoxProjCode.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: please look into  @paul bica answer which perhaps meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code inserting it after Next currentrow

```
With ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End With
```

Sorry I misread your question. For deleting empty rows try to modify the standard code given hereunder which I use for deletion of empty rows.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
  Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim LastRow As Long
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  LastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   With ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
   End With
End Sub
```

please make sure to make a copy of data before attempting deletion during testing code.

Comment: Hi means i have to create a new Sub instead of adjusting the code which i have posted? @skkakkar

Answer (score 1):

I optimized your posted code and changed `.EntireRow.ClearContents` to `.EntireRow.Delete`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandDeleteButton1_Click()
    Const CL As String = "B"
    Dim fRow As Long, lRow As Long, fnd As Variant, v As Variant, prjCode As String

    fRow = 4
    With Worksheets("Program Status Summary")

        lRow = .Range(CL & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        prjCode = Val(TextBoxProjCode.Text)

        v = Application.Transpose(.Range(CL & fRow & ":" & CL & lRow))
        fnd = Application.Match(prjCode, Split(Join(v, ","), ","), 0)

        If Not IsError(fnd) Then .Cells(fnd + fRow - 1, 2).EntireRow.Delete '<-----

    End With
    TextBoxProjCode.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: nice approach. I am curious to know what your `v = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(.Range("B" & fRow & ":B" & lastrow)), ","), ",")` is trying to do

Comment: @skkakkar: thanks. My main goal was to eliminate the loop and Match is  faster than Find, but it was giving me some issues that I need to look into. The split is creating a 1 dimensional array, even though a contiguous range of cells should work as well (as in `.UsedRange.Columns(2)`)

Comment: Alright thank you i will give it a try and will let you know of the result!

Comment: Hi i tried changing my code from '.EntireRow.ClearContents to .EntireRow.Delete' and it works! Thanks alot @paulbica